# C++ try / catch (new to programming and not much info about this clause)

Tags: c++

I am new to programming and am having trouble with try / catch clauses.

Here is an example from a textbook that I have:

```
int main( ) 
{
   char *ptr;

   try {
      ptr = new char[ 1000000000 ];
   }

   catch( … ) {
      cout << "Too many elements" << endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

I have tried to look online for a further explanation and the textbook does not exactly tell me what what these clauses actually do or what it is used for.

Any information would be helpful.

EDIT: The textbook I am using is:
C++: Classes and Data Structures by Jeffrey Childs

Comment: This is C++ [exception handling](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/exceptions.html). Another link is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6dekhbbc.aspx

Comment: This is a horrible example in many ways. Wash your eyes out and then read the doc.

Comment: FWIW I wouldn't get into exception handling and exceptions if you are new to C++

Comment: @AJG85: It is hard to work with existing C++ libraries without picking up at least something about exceptions. It is unfortunate, but only few libraries support a "no-exceptions" mode.

Comment: @VladLazarenko I'm not saying don't learn it, just don't learn it first if you're a newbie ;-)

Comment: @VladLazarenko: "Unfortunate" is hardly an apt description. Exceptions are fundamental and essential to the C++ object model (think about constructors). There's no way to remove exceptions and still have "C++".

Comment: @KerrekSB: You are right, you cannot indicate error in constructors... well, you can.. using TSS and errno, but who wants a C++ like that, right?

Comment: For beginners you can ignore exceptions. If the code works then it works if there is an exception you are unlikely to be able to do anything about it so let it kill the application. At this early stage of learning/development C++ the only useful thing to do is log an error message so you know an exception caused your program to exit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try catch is a way of handling exceptions:

```
try
{
      // Do work in here
      // If any exceptions are generated then the code in here is stopped.
      // and a jump is made to the catch block.
      // to see if the exception can be handled.

      // An exception is generated when somebody uses throw.
      // Either you or one of the functions you call.

      // In your case new can throw std::bad_alloc
      // Which is derived from std::runtime_error which is derived from std::exception

}
// CATCH BLOCK HERE.
```

The catch block is where you define what exceptions you want to handle.

```
// CATCH BLOCK
catch(MyException const& e)
{
     // Correct a MyException
}
catch(std::exception const& e)
{
     // Correct a std::exception
     // For example this would cat any exception derived from std::exception
}
```

You can have as many catch blocks as you like. If you exception matches any of the catch expressions in the catch statement then the associated block of code is executed. If no catch expressions matches an exception then the stack is unwound until it finds a higher level catch block and the processes is repeated (this can cause the application to exit if no matching catch block is found).

Note: If multiple catch expressions match then the lexically first one is used. Only one or none of the catch blocks will be executed. If none then the compiler will look for a higher level try/catch.

There is also a catch anything clause

```
catch(...)
{
     // This is a catch all.
     // If the exception is not listed above this will catch any exception.
}
```

So how does this apply to your code.

```
int main( ) 
{
   char *ptr;

   try
   {
      // This calls ::new() which can potentially throw std::bad_alloc
      // If this happens then it will look for a catch block.
      ptr = new char[ 1000000000 ];


     // If the ::new() works then nothing happens and you pointer `ptr`
     // is valid and code continues to execute. 
   }
   catch( … )
   {
      // You only have one catch block that catches everything.
      // So if there are any statements that generate an exception this will catch
      // the excetption and execute this code.

      cout << "Too many elements" << endl;
   }
   // As you have caught all exceptions the code will continue from here.
   // Either after the try block finishes successfully or
   // After an exception has been handled by the catch block.

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: this is a really great explanation for me. Thanks for the time to show me how it relates to the crappy example provided to me.

Answer (score 2):

A try-catch is the C++ construct for exception handling. Google 'C++ exceptions'.

Answer (score -1):

Try-catch blocks are used to trap errors in the code.

At the most basic level, errors occur because the program tries to execute an invalid instruction.  That instruction (read: line of code) could be invalid for a number of reasons.  In your specific instance, the instruction could be invalid if your program was not able to allocate 1,000,000,000 bytes of memory to story your ptr.  The most common exception is trying to access a bad pointer, which is called a Null Pointer Exception, which occurs when you try to perform some action on an Object that either has not been created, or has been deleted (or got corrupt).  You will learn to hate that exception.

Using catch(...) tells the program to execute the code inside the catch block if any error occurs inside the code within the try block.  There you can handle your error and try to find someway to either fix the error condition or gracefully exit that module.

You can also catch specific errors, which you can find out more about here : http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/

Comment: There are no "Null Pointer Exceptions" in C++.

Comment: This is a very poor explanation that misses almost all points about C++ exceptions. They do most certainly not serve to "trap errors".

Comment: I think this gives a decent overview of exceptions and try/catch blocks even if the details are iffy.

Comment: Most probably the new operator, which internally calls some memory allocation function, throws an error by using the C++ throw operator to raise an exception.

Answer (score -5):

If you already know C, `try/catch` achieves the same thing as `setjmp/longjmp` when used for error handling. Think of `try` as code for the if condition of `setjmp` and `catch` code for else of `setjmp`. This makes `longjmp` equivalent to `throw`  in C++, which is used to throw an exception. In your example, probably, the `new` operator, which calls some memory allocation function internally, throws an exception on seeing a very large number as input by using the C++ `throw` operator.

```
void a()
{
      .......
      longjmp(buf,1);      // <--- similar to throw
      .......
}

if ( !setjmp(buf) )        // <--- similar to try
{
      .......
      a(); 
      .......                
} 
else                       // <--- similar to catch
{                    
      .......          
}
```

`try/catch` is a bit more sophisticated than `setjmp/longjmp`, as for `setjmp/longjmp` you will need to declare variables which are modified in between `setjmp/longjmp` calls as volatile, which is not necessary for `try/catch`.

Comment: someone new to programming probably isn't familiar with `setjmp/longjmp` either.

Comment: setjmp/longjmp pair is not used to implement exceptions. Time to refresh your knowledge :)

Comment: Vlad Lazerenko - Who said setjmp/longjmp can't be used for exception handling. If the wikipedia articles says so, then it is indeed used for it. Infact, the old __try and __catch macros found in Microsoft C compilers were probably using setjmp/longjmp.

Comment: @Mooing, he maybe new to C++ but not C.

Comment: @MetallicPriest: Wikipedia is no source for the knowledge of how exception handling is implemented in modern compilers. And setjmp/longjmp is obviously not the case. Your "probably" here is the key. It was, 20 years ago, but not anymore. And not in C compiler for sure.

Comment: @MetallicPriest: -1 Unfortunately the analogy is very flawed as the try/catch does a lot more work. Thus using it to explain exceptions to a beginner is counter productive.